# Fire Adwords remarketing list on virtual page view

Tags: google-ads-api, gtag.js

Hi I'm trying to fire a specific remarketing list tag with Google Tag Manager. In the debugging everything works perfectly. I'm triggering the specific list tag and the global Adwords remarketing tag and it works. Although, nothing populates in Adwords.

I've a statement in GTM which triggers the tag if the virtual page view equals an URL and it works.

I've tried to different tags for the specific lists:

```
    <script>
  gtag('event', 'conversion', {
      'send_to': 'AW-XXXXXXXXX/ZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZ',
      'value': 1.0,
      'currency': 'SEK',
      'aw_remarketing_only': true
  });
</script>
```

and

```
    <script>
  gtag('event', 'conversion', {
      'send_to': 'AW-XXXXXXXXX/ZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZ'});
</script>
```

The problem is that the lists in Adwords doesn't populates and I've checked that the specific url have had traffic which should indicate that the trigger would be fired.

Thanks!

Comment: Fixed your tags - even though gtag.js references googletagmanager.com in the loading script it is not actually the same as Google Tag Manager.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okey so we're using GTM to do this now to simply fire a tag with the information in the code above. Don't need to use custom HTML/script to do this.